# Spring Integration and UriEndpointMapping

Tags: java, spring-integration

I've managed to setup a web service using Spring Integration that goes through a ws inbound gateway and then on to a service activator. Now I want to change the setup so that the inbound gateway is no longer the default endpoint mapping because there are other existing services that need to be available. When I change the UriEndpointMapping so that the gateway is no longer the default endpoint, I get this message: org.springframework.ws.server.EndpointNotFound - No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage ....

I've tried changing the UriEndpointMapping to set the mappings property where I set the url to the gateway reference, and I've tried setting the endpointMap property and used a number of different keys, all without success. The Spring Integration documentation doesn't indicate how to set the UriEndpointMapping for multiple endpoints that are mapped to gateways, and the examples I've found on the web don't work for me either. I'm at a loss on how to proceed.

FYI, this configuration needs to be done in a spring xml file if at all possible.

This works:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.UriEndpointMapping">
    <property name="defaultEndpoint" ref="reconGateway"/>
</bean>
```

This is my latest try, but it fails.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.UriEndpointMapping">
    <property name="usePath" value="true"/>
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="http://localhost:8081/intfacade-web/reconService">reconGateway</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Oh, I have tried with just the path and that didn't work either.

Thanks!

Anyone?